# Determining the distribution of a given function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given a r.v. $X$ with distribution function $F(x) = 1-(1-\exp(x))_+$, is this some specific distribution?

Basically it has the form $F(x) = \mathbb{1}_{x_2 > 0}+\exp(x_2)\mathbb{1}_{x_2<0}$, but I don't recognize if it's some sort of "known" distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x \geq 0, F(x)=1$.

Thus we have only to consider the case $x<0$.

By definition of a cdf, $F_X(x):=P(X<x)=1-(1-e^x)_+$

Taking the contrary event: $P(X\geq x)=(1-e^x)_+$

which is equivalent to

$$P(X\geq x)=1-e^x$$

(because for $x<0$, $e^{x}<1,$ thus $1-e^x>0.$)

This can be written in another way:

$$\tag{1}P(-X \leq -x)=1-e^x$$

Setting $y:=-x$ (the variables) and $Y=-X$ (the random variables), (1) can be written:

$$\tag{2}P(Y \leq y)=1-e^{-y}$$

which is the well known expression of the cdf of an Exp(1) random variable.

Thus the answer is yes, there is a connection with a known distribution:

> $X=-Y$ is the opposite of an Exp(1) random variable.

(see representation of its cdf below)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y\sim Exp(1)$ then $-Y$ has the desired cdf.